# Casting from 'NSPersistentStoreResult' to unrelated type 'Entity' always fails

Tags: swift, core-data

I am creating a small app to learn the many to many relationships in CoreData. However using the code below I get an error casting from my NSFetchResult to my Entity class ('Groepering'):

[image]

I do not see any difference from samples I found on the internet compared to my project, why does the cast still fail?

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext

let fetchRequest : NSFetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Entity")

    do {
        let fetchResults = try managedContext.executeRequest(fetchRequest)
        let groeperingen = fetchResults as! [Entity]
        // Here I get the Error: ^

    } catch {
        print("Error")
}
```

Comment: It's just a typo : `managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)`

Answer (score 113, accepted):

Use `executeFetchRequest` method of NSManagedObjectContext when performing a NSFetchRequest.

**Edit Swift 3**: For Swift 3, use:

```
let result = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
```

Comment: Thanks! After reading it for a thousand times i still kept looking over it and reading it correctly in my head.

Comment: In Swift 3, this command has changed to     `NSManagedObjectContext.fetch(NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>)`  
[Link to Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coredata/nsmanagedobjectcontext/1506672-fetch)

Comment: I was calling 
`let result = try managedContext.execute(fetchRequest)`
and spend some hours to find wrong method typo execute to fetch

Answer (score 16):

I recently converted my code to Swift 3 and ran into this same error, though not because of a typo. It seems that the new, equivalent function call is `let fetchResults = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)`.

Comment: This worked for me in Swift 3. There is also a managedObjectContext.execute(request) method, but that produces the same problems as above.

Comment: @PabloMartinez I cast the results using `let fetchResults = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest) as! [MySubclass]`.

Comment: @PabloMartinez also a `let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<MySubClass>(entityName: "MyModel")` will make your fetchResults to be casted to `[MySubClass]`

Comment: @JavierP (Swift 4.2) I tried the code in your comment - the console advised me "Cannot specialize a non-generic definition" - is it possible something changed between Swift 3 -> 4?

Answer (score 4):

This is the solution (updated for Swift 4):

```
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Device")
    do {
        if let results = try persistentContainer.viewContext.fetch(fetchRequest) as? [NSManagedObject] {
            for result in results {
                if let name = result.value(forKey: "name") as? String, let type = result.value(forKey: "type") as? String {
                    print(name, "is an ", type)
                }
            }
        }
    } catch {
        print("Failed to fetch data request.")
    }
```