# Cast a NSPersistentStoreResult to array

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, casting, swift3

Hi I'm having trouble with the code below. Specifically the if let statement gives a Cast from `NSPeristentStoreResult` to unrelated type [Item] always fails warning. I'm using Swift 3.01.

It seems like this should be simple to do. The book I'm following was written using an earlier version of Swift. Thanks for your indulgence.

```
func demo(){

let request = NSFetchRequest<Item>(entityName: "Item")

  do {
     if let items = try CDHelper.shared.context.execute(request) as? [Item] {
        for item in items {
           if let name = item.name {
              print("Fetched Managed Object = '\(name)'")
           }
        }
     }
  } catch {
     print("Error executing a fetch request: \(error)")
  }
 }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52830702/1673192

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use `fetch()` instead of `execute()`:

```
if let items = try CDHelper.shared.context.fetch(request)
...
```

Or use `perform` on your context:

```
 CDHelper.shared.context.perform {
      let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Item> = Item.fetchRequest()            
      let items = try! fetchRequest.execute() 
      for item in items {
           if let name = item.name {
                print("Fetched Managed Object = '\(name)'")
           }
      }
}
```